# Returning result of query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to return query result but i don't know how to `return query result`, please help me !

```
$this->db->query(my query);
return $this->db->query()->result
```

Not Working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to return the **query** then you can use the below workaround.

```
$this->db->query(my query);
$query = $this->db->last_query();
return $query;
```

If you want to return the **result** as well the use below code:

```
$query = $this->db->query(my query);
return $query->result();
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, it very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Take `$this->db->query(my query);` into a variable, and then use `result()`

```
$query = $this->db->query(my query);
return $query->result();
```

Comment: there is an error like this Call to a member function result() on array

Comment: @AdjieSatrioPrabowo what about : `return $query;` ?

Comment: it's working, you very helpful, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can directly return the value:

```
return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM myTable")->result();
```

Is there any error using `result`? why do it caused error? It should be working.

Comment: thank you for the answer, it very helpful it's working now

Answer (score 0):

Step-1: Assign it into a variable

```
$query = $this->db->query(your query);
```

Step-2: Then you can use it as follows

```
return $query->result();
```

or

```
return $query->result_array();
```